# Trying to create hyperlinks in the <text-angular> with ng-change but when user paste URL, it moves cursor to the start

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<text-angular name="myEditor" class="deal-notes" ta-
toolbar-class="btn-toolbar pull-right" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 500}" 
ng-change="updateDeal('deal.notes');" ng-blur="makeLinks()" ta-toolbar-
group-class="btn-group" ta-toolbar="[['bold','italics', 'insertLink']]" ng-
model="deal.notes">
```

Trying to create hyperlinks in the  with `ng-change` but when user paste URL, it moves cursor to the start.

```
<script> 
    function makeLinks(){
        var linkedText = Autolinker.link($scope.deal.notes, {stripPrefix: false});
        $scope.deal.notes = linkedText;                                                                                 
        updateDeal('deal.notes');
    }
<script>
```

Comment: For future: This question is not relevant to Angular or TextAngular. It is plain javascript, so you might want to rephrase your question,

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do, is to store the position of caret before you make any modifications to the html/text. After the changes have been made, you set the caret back to the original position (or you calculate the new position according to changes)

So modify the makeLinks() function like this

```
function makeLinks() 
    {
      var caretPosition = editorElement.prop("selectionStart");
      var linkedText = Autolinker.link($scope.deal.notes, {stripPrefix: false});
      $scope.deal.notes = linkedText;                                                                                 
      updateDeal('deal.notes');

      // set the cursor back to correct position
      editorElement.setSelectionRange(caretPosition, caretPosition);
    }
```

Comment: it was meant as a variable which points to your instance of `<angular-text>`. You can fill it by several ways. Eg. document.getElementById(). But that is a hack. Maybe you can extend the AngularText with custom behaviour, see https://coderwall.com/p/-8vjxa/cleanly-extend-3rd-party-angularjs-directives

Comment: Modified this code:
function makeLinks() 
  { 
    var editorElement = document.getElementById("edt");
    
    var caretPosition = editorElement.prop("selectionStart");
    var linkedText = Autolinker.link($scope.deal.notes, {stripPrefix: false});
    $scope.deal.notes = linkedText;                                                                                 
    updateDeal('deal.notes');
    // set the cursor back to correct position
    editorElement.setSelectionRange(caretPosition, caretPosition);

Error: editorElement is not defined

Comment: Can you please respond to my query?

Comment: I do not know the context, but it seems that you are calling `makeLinks()` too soon. That it is called before the element with `id="edt"` is attached to DOM. Or maybe it does not have that ID at all